# Tensorflow / Keras stack images on channels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Imagine the following setup:

- image data shape: (302, 482, 3)
- images per sample: 2
- batch size: 100

My data loader produces the following shape: (100, 2, 302, 482, 3) - the goal is to stack the two input images on the channel axis to (100, 302, 482, 6).

Without the batch dimension (so x has shape (2, 302, 482, 3) ) its quite easy:

```
# x.shape = (2, 302, 482, 3)
stacked = tf.concat(x, axis=-1)
# stacked.shape = (302, 482, 6)
```

But I'cant figure it out to do the same operations, when the batch dimension is added.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, best way to go is to concatenate to 2 images **before** the input of the network (with numpy), providing the network with dimensions (302, 482, 6, ), unless you want to process it higher in the network. It depends on your goal.
Batch size don't matter when writing your layers. `tf.concat` will proceed just the same, no matter the batch size.